# Action don't change the state on reducer test with jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test my reducer, but my initial state don't change when I dispatch an action on the test.

That's my reducer:

```
    export default function login(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.SET_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    case Types.SET_LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {email: action.user.email, password: action.user.password},
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

That's my test:

```
it('should handle SET_ERROR', () => {
      const setErrorAction = {type: 'SET_ERROR', error: 'a'};
      expect(login(INITIAL_STATE, setErrorAction)).toEqual({
        ...INITIAL_STATE,
        error: 'a',
      });
});
```

And that's my test result:

```
 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
    -   "error": "a",
    +   "error": "",
        "user": Object {
          "email": "",
          "password": "",
        },
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Types.SET_ERROR` === 'SET_ERROR' ?

Comment: You're correct! Thanks for helping me, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Feel free to answer your question with the exact solution to resolve this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that Types.SET_ERROR === 'SET_ERROR' wasn't correct.

@segFault helped me to realize that the name of my action was different, so because of that my action wasn't dispatched.